# Multiple swing dialog boxes

Tags: java, swing

I was wondering if it was possible if I could open Multiple swing dialog boxes simultaneously.

Comment: Surely your code and compiler could answer this for you. ?

Answer (score 2):

Can't think of any reason why you couldn't, but surely this is something that would take you 5 minutes to write a simple app just to test it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, just make sure the secondary dialog is owned by the primary one.  I think I've seen some weird z-order issues if they're not parented correctly.  Swing can also be temperamental at times.